# Date format effect on Internationalization

Tags: java

Is it possible to send date in another formats like french(dd-mm-yyyy) or us(mm-dd-yyyy).Currently I am using mysql for data base in it date format is yyyy-mm-dd. So is there any effect on java program side. If it is possible to send and receive date in any format in internationalization concept in java then how is it possible.

Comment: "send" to where?  Your question is not clear.  Please show some code and specific examples that you are having trouble with.

Comment: If you're storing dates in a database as strings instead of as a numeric type, You're Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

**Smart objects, not dumb strings.**

Exchange objects with your database, not strings. The job of your JDBC driver is to mediate on your behalf between the Java types and the database types.

Localization is irrelevant to the database. Localize for presentation in the user-interface.

## Strings are not date-time values

The date-time types in your database do not have "a format". You are confusing textual representations of date-time values with the values themselves. You parse a string to get a date-time value, and you generate a string to display a date-time value, but the value itself is not a string.

## Use date-time types in database

Study the [date-time data types offered by your database, MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) in your case. Define your columns with those types.

Do not store date-time values as text in your database, just as you would never store numbers as text in your database.

## Database

Use [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to move data in and out of your database. Use either  modern or legacy approach.

### Modern JDBC

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange java.time objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

For database columns of type:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.Instant`
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, `LocalDateTime`
- `DATE` column, `LocalDate`
- `TIME`, `LocalTime`

### Legacy JDBC

If not yet on JDBC 4.2, call on the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) types to set/get date-time objects to/from your database via [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

- java.sql.Timestamp = date & time
- java.sql.Date = date-only
- java.sql.Time = time-only

Unfortunately those java.sql types are old classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Minimize your use of them. Immediately convert to the types defined in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## Localization

Use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and its `ofLocalized…` methods to generate strings automatically localized to any [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) such as [Québec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH), [France](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#FRANCE), and [United States](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US).

I'll not go further as all of these topics have already been asked and answered many times over in Stack Overflow. Search for many more discussions and examples.